# Rails error routing issue (blank page)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

having a weird issue with Rails (3.2.15)

I messed around with nicer error pages, but as that was suppressing ALL errors at one point I needed to revert so I can see errors in the log files.

I had:

- installed gem: 'exception_notification'
- added initialisation code for that in the relevant environment file (config.middleware...)
- added routes to catch errors 'get '/500', :to => 'errors#server_error' ', same for 404/422
- added rescue statements in application controller "rescue_from Exception, with: lambda { |exception| render_error 500, exception }"  etc, same for 404 and render method to render custom pages

Now, I didn't want any of that any more as stated, so I have removed all of the above, ran bundle install, etc. and deployed to my staging environment.

However, NOW I get blank pages on any errors (500 or 404), I don't see that standard rails 'Something went wrong page' at all, (though it is still in /public)

I don't understand why I'm not back at the default error handling, I have no 'rescue' statements anywhere, and no routes that mess with errors.

The log file on 500 shows the full error that occurs and then just:
rendered [page I was trying to see] within layouts/application (50.4ms)
"Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 184.9ms"
[error details]

Why am I not getting my default Rails error behaviour, I'm not sure what I'm missing here??

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!!

Comment: If this is happening only on the deployed site you likely forgot to run "bundle update" to update the Gemfile.lock file, otherwise I haven't got a clue as there is not enough info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turned out I had forgotten to remove this line in config/application.rb :

```
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

since I removed any routes to do with errors it was therefore showing blank pages.

d'oh